Inconsistent Final Trade Prices: Why is the Last Trade of the Day Often Erroneous?
I am working on extracting technical indicators from market data and need to obtain the daily close price for assets. In my dataset, which includes all trades for each day along with their prices and timestamps, I’ve noticed an anomaly: the price of the final trade of the day is often (~1 in 20 times) inconsistent with the rest of the trades. In some cases, this price is even negative, which indicates that it is definitely incorrect.
As a temporary solution, I am using the second-to-last trade of the day as the close price, since this value seems to be reliable and unaffected by the data quality issues seen in the final trade.
Can anyone explain why this issue might be occurring specifically with the final trade of the day? I’m concerned that there may be a more fundamental issue at play.

What market is this and what is the source of data for that market? What you may be seeing is an out-of-order-trade that was made earlier in the day but is only being reported now, at the close, in order to "get it in" before the market closes. But this is only speculation on my part. Some databases flag these trades so you can avoid them. But need more info for a better answer.
